# Checkpoint mechanism for Z3

Tags: z3

I am planning to do some work with the Z3 SMT solver from Microsoft Research that will run on a compute server with an execution time limit. I expect that the job will exceed this limit. The recommended policy for this computing center is to use "checkpoints" and to invoke a series of jobs, each of which picks up the checkpoint from the previous job and continues working. In this way, no process runs for more than the execution time limit, so other users have a chance to run their jobs too, but the total amount of compute time used can exceed the timeout for a single job.

Does Z3 have support for reading and writing checkpoints?

By "checkpoint", I mean a file that serializes (some part of) the internal state of the Z3 solver, such that if the Z3 process writes a checkpoint and exits, and then a second Z3 process is started that reads the checkpoint file, after reading it back the state of the new Z3 process is identical to the state of the previous process (so the solver doesn't start again, but continues solving from where it left off).

As an alternative, instead of checkpointing the entire solver, is it possible to read the database of learned clauses (or other inference databases built internally by Z3)? This could make it possible to do a form of checkpointing by augmenting the input file with learned clauses, although it might not be as efficient as a "real" checkpoint of the entire internal state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Z3 does not have facilities that achieve all those goals already built in. Z3 goal and solver objects can be serialized to a string in SMT2 format via the [Z3_goal_to_string](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__capi.html#gafbd3f124e070b1aa0cbcc76fabbfceee) and [Z3_solver_to_string](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__capi.html#gaf52e41db4b12a84188b80255454d3abb) functions; these could be used for check-pointing, but they will not save any learnt clauses that weren't in the goal or the solver before the last search was started.

In case the main goal is to re-start an intricate interaction, perhaps a Z3 interaction log could be helpful (see [Z3_open_log](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__capi.html#ga8db77098c469027412cd9c9321b2cb42)). These logs can be replayed, but again, learned clauses, etc, are not saved.

Comment: Thanks for your citations. None of them would really help me here, as preserving the complete solver state including learnt clauses is more useful than preserving an interaction (which I would already have since this will run on a batch system). I might look into adding such a mechanism to Z3 and submitting a patch.